Are freelance platforms designed for low-income locales?
As I've noticed, Freelancer, Upwork, Guru, and PeoplePerHour are mostly about low-paid jobs. Many employers there, for example, are from countries with a low cost of living and offer low rates for complex or lengthy jobs, or from countries with a high cost of living, but still look for cheap labour. There are only a few jobs that offer acceptable rates, but freelancers from low-income countries can of course bid on them as well, thus probably diverting most of the business away from freelancers in expensive countries.
One strategy I could think of is to complete a few low-paid jobs, get positive feedback, and then bid only on decently paid jobs. Do you think this approach is feasible? At the end of the day, a freelancer from an expensive country will probably need to leave these freelance platforms and try a different approach to finding clients. But how many freelancers succeed in that? This question really concerns me because, despite having a portfolio showcasing some decent projects, and despite bidding on low-rate projects, I've been unable to get even a first job, and have to buy more and more "Connects" on Upwork, seemingly to no avail. This is quite frustrating of course, and makes me feel like programming/app/web/script development jobs are unappreciated these days.
I live in Norway, one of the most expensive countries in Europe, so freelancing for fair pay is important.

Right now, there are a lot of people who have been let go from major Tech companies. They are hunting for jobs on those platforms. Thus, there are a lot more people looking for projects than quality projects. A number of places are in a "tech recession" which means that far fewer projects are being funded.
In the past, there have been postings from companies in Norway on those platforms. Companies from Sweden, Germany, and Britain have also posted numerous projects on those platforms. There are projects out there, but a lot harder to find.
There is no "sure way" strategy. Persistence in trying is all I can suggest. Other people are suggesting focusing on offering consulting to company owners about how AI can be used in their business.
Networking might be a more productive strategy right now. Most projects do not get posted on boards. Finding people who have a problem and the willingness to spend money to solve that problem is the key.
